# Apache, Foswiki Error on OpenBSD - Internal Error - Logs say exec of /htdocs/foswiki/bin/configure failed

Tags: apache, perl, openbsd, foswiki

I am using OpenBSD installed with perl, apache, firefox, gedit.  I am trying to run foswiki on OpenBSD.

Whenever i try to run

```
http://127.0.0.1/foswiki/bin/configure
```

it gives 500 internal  server Error.  When i checked Logs it revels following information.

> [Wed Mar 19 08:24:33 2014] [error] (2)No such file or directory: exec
>   of /htdocs/foswiki/bin/configure failed
>
> [Wed Mar 19 08:24:33 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of
>   script headers: /htdocs/foswiki/bin/configure

Can someone guide on what is the issue and how do i resolve. ?

Regards

Location of files:   `/var/www/htdocs/foswiki`

The `httpd.conf` file has following configuration.

```
> ServerType standalone

     Timeout 300 
KeepAlive On 
MaxKeepAliveRequests  100 
KeepAliveTimeout 15 
Include /var/www/conf/modules/*.conf

> DocumentRoot "/var/www/htdocs"
> 
> 
> ScriptAlias /foswiki/bin "/var/www/htdocs/foswiki/bin"
> 
> Alias /foswiki "/var/www/htdocs/foswiki" Alias /foswiki/pub
> "/var/www/foswiki/pub"
> 
> <Directory "/var/www/htdocs/foswiki">
>     Order Allow,Deny
>     Allow from all
>     Deny from env=blockAccess </Directory>
> 
> <Directory "/var/www/htdocs">
>     Order Allow,Deny
>     Allow from all
>     Deny from env=blockAccess </Directory>
> 
> 
> <Directory "/var/www/htdocs/foswiki/bin">
>     AllowOverride None
>     Order Allow,Deny
>     Allow from all
>     Deny from env=blockAccess
> 
>     Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
>     SetHandler cgi-script
> 
> </Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe i'm wrong, but in the OpenBsd the apache is chrooted by default, and the foswiki configuration calling external programs. (and of course it want call `perl` - what is (imho) not allowed with a default OpenBSD apache config).

You can verify this, by copying the `cgi-bin/printenv`, from the default `cgi-bin` directory to the foswiki `bin` set the perm: `chmod 755 /var/www/htdocs/foswiki/bin/printenv` and point your browser to

```
http://127.0.0.1/foswiki/bin/printenv
```

And you should to get the same error.

For testing, if you want run your apache WITHOUT chroot, you can try add to

```
/etc/rc.conf
```

the next:

```
httpd_flags="-u"
```

and restart...

Comment: Hi jm666, Your input was valuable. it did worked.  Thanks a ton  - regards